# Clojure core.logic conde; quit if condition fails/succeded

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

does anyone know how to quit / try the next condition in a conde, when a condition fails?

As example:

```
(run* q (conde 
   [(conditionA) (conditionB) (conditionC)]
   [(conditionA) (conditionD) (conditionE)]
   [(conditionF) (conditionB) (conditionG)]
))
```

If the first goal

```
[(conditionA) (conditionB) (conditionC)]
```

fails at condition B it should be stop immediately, because the goal

```
[(conditionF) (conditionB) (conditionG)]
```

is definitely true.

Thanks!

Comment: What you are describing seems to be exactly how `conde` works.  What is your real problem?

Comment: I have following lines:
[(== true (:site term)) (== :all (:operator term)) (== q {:lbr [(assoc (choose-c-from-uod-for-v (:variable term) (:sub term)) :site true)],:rbr [] :rule (get-rule term)})]

[(== false (:site term)) (== :all (:operator term)) (== q {:rbr [(assoc (new-c-in-uod (:variable term) (:sub term)) :site false)],:lbr [] :rule (get-rule term)})]

But when i call this with term = {:site false, :operator all} both conditions are called until the end...

Comment: Try editing the question to explain more of the problem (like what you said in the previous comment—which is hard to read because it's in a comment).